# Docker not able to run nodejs npm

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

When I run below commands in a *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM ruby:2.3

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install nodejs npm -y

RUN apt-get install vim -y

RUN apt-get install memcached -y
```

I get below error:

> Sending build context to Docker daemon  29.74MB
>
> Step 1/12 : FROM ruby:2.3
>
> ---> 09c6ceeef3bc
>
> Step 2/12 : RUN apt-get update
>
> ---> Using cache
>
> ---> c41c3235c3ba
>
> Step 3/12 : RUN apt-get install nodejs npm -y
>
> ---> Running in b0d407900cbd
>
> Reading package lists...
>
> Building dependency tree...
>
> Reading state information...
>
> **E: Unable to locate package npm
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install nodejs npm -y' returned a
>   non-zero code: 100**

Please suggest a solution, thank you in advance.

Comment: Small hint: when you move all `apt-get` commands separated by `;` or `&&` into one `RUN` instruction and execute `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` at the end to clean the cache then you will have much smaller result Docker image.

Answer (score 9):

Docker image `ruby:2.3` is based on Debian 9 Stretch where is older `nodejs` package and no `npm` package.

You can do it like this:

```
RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y curl gnupg; \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -; \
    apt-get install -y nodejs; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

At first it installs `curl` to be able to download setup script and `gnupg` is needed by that setup script.

You can read more on nodejs official web: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: Right, or just use the node image.

Comment: yes, I tried the steps to install nodejs with curl command, docker image build is successful, thank you very much for pointing that out.
but the issue is we have a rube app, that does not run with this image, 
developers says attached errors are due to improper installation of node.

please see this link for error logs

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gTa4ik0WxkQkiRs3ioflk7iYPj5oI1Bj

Comment: couple of months before, below command worked and we were able to build docker images

FROM ruby:2.3

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install nodejs npm -y

Comment: Then try it in this way: `RUN apt-get update; 
    apt-get install -y nodejs; 
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`
It will install older `nodejs` which is packaged with Debian. Notice that `npm` is not in the install command.
And you can also try to add this instruction into Dockerfile: `ENV EXECJS_RUNTIME=Node`.

Comment: please see the output, wont install
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VS4pooBSSB9UPWEPPvTSxKarh0PlsHou

Comment: Because you have `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` before `apt-get install -y nodejs` and that makes no sense. You have to install `nodejs` at first and after that clean the apt cache.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to install nodesetup from https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x
add code like in your docker file after RUN apt-get update statement.

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -;

Note: You are creating unnecessarily layers in Docker Image with RUN statement you can combine those statements